# How good are current PCB debugging tools?

Tags: pcb, soldering, jtag, testing, manufacturing

I'm a newbie in the field of manufacturing, and I'm hoping to get a broad understanding of the field. After you get PCBs manufactured, I understand that you need to check for mechanical damage, scratched copper, through-hole misalignment, cold solders, solder bridging, etc.

If I understand correctly, you can check for these either (1) visually, (2) with "bed of nails" test bed, or (3) with JTAG.

In what contexts are each of these 3 methods used? Are there other methods besides these? Is one preferred over the others? How effective, cheap, and easy are each of these solutions? What are the hardest parts of the process of debugging?

Comment: By "after you get PCBs manufactured" do you mean bare board, or boards with components installed?  There are different possibilities for testing depending on which stage of manufacturing you are asking about.

Comment: Good point, I meant boards with components installed. But I'm not very familiar with the process - I understand these are 2 separate steps, are they ever done by a single manufacturer? If they're done by 2 how would you coordinate it?

Comment: Depends on how many you are building, and the cost of each. And the testing that you described is preliminary, the final test is usually a functional test.

Comment: Gotcha. When you say preliminary, does that mean that they are done after PVT/EVT/DVT or that are they applied to the actual devices you ship to customers, but before a functional test?

Comment: I am only discussing production testing on actual devices shipped to customers. The terminalogy used is not always universal. Final testing must ensure that the product meets all requirements. Earlier testing is optional to help debug. A cost-benefit analysis must be performed. The non-recurring cost can be high. If your yield rate is 99.9% and your boards are cheap, you might not attempt to debug and scrap the 0.1%.

Comment: Any good PCB fab will offer some basic testing before shipping the boards to you, so I'd recommend looking into that at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

> How good are current PCB debugging tools?

Modern tools are very good at testing CCAs.

Here are some of the common tools that are used in the electronics industry.

**Automated Optical Inspection (AOI)**
[AOI equipment](https://www.pcbgogo.com/Blog/What_Is_Automated_Optical_Inspection__AOI__in_A_PCB_.html#:~:text=Automated%20optical%20inspection%20(AOI)%20is%20a%20machine%2Dbased%20technique,well%20as%20component%20placement%20defects.) uses a camera to look for missing parts, mis-placed parts, and bad solder joints.

This is typically the first test after a board is assembled.

**X-RAY Inspection**
If the board contains no-lead parts or Ball Grid Array (BGA) parts, then AOI can't inspect all the solder joints.  In this case X-Ray inspection equipment is used to verify that the solder joints under these parts don't have defects.

**Automated Test equipment (ATE)**
After being assembled the CCAs can be plugged into automated test equipment.  The ATE applies input signals and commands to the card and then measures the response.  ATE can perform tests much faster and more accurately than factory technicians can test by hand.

Good ATE should make measurements for each function that the card is required to perform.

ATE usually involves some custom-built hardware and wiring harnesses to test each design.

**Flying Probe**
Companies like [SPEA](https://www.spea.com/product-category/flying-probe-test/) make flying probe equipment.

For bare PWBs, the board house can conduct tests for electrical continuity and isolation using a flying probe.

For assembled boards, a flying probe can make measurements of individual components.  This can be used to verify that the parts are the correct part (right value of resistor/capacitor), or that they were placed correctly (diode not backwards).

**JTAG**
For boards that have chips with JTAG boundary scan, this method can be used to measure each IO pin on the chips in the scan chain.  It can also be used to inject stimulus from those IO pins to other chips (which may or may not be on the chain).

Comment: Thanks for breaking down these different options! For an engineer who's working on the design side (but may eventually have to deal with CMs), which (if any...) of these tools would be most worth getting familiar with?

Comment: @AchintyaAgarwal If you are working as a design engineer, you can typically let the manufacturing side deal with AOI, X-Ray inspection, and flying probe stuff.  You may find yourself using JTAG during design verification testing.  If your company has a separate test engineering group, you may work with them to develop ATE.  If not, you may find yourself designing it.  Unless you supply very detailed design documents and specifications, I wouldn't expect any third-party manufacturers to be able to design ATE for your stuff without your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to discuss testing as a stand alone entity.   Depending on your product and industry, there may be multiple assembly/inspection/test steps in the manufacturing flow. Here's what's typically done for hi rel production systems.

First of all, we usually don't do x-ray inspection on a routine basis.  That's reserved for troubleshooting.  JTAG is usually only used to program FPGAs and like devices on the board.  That leaves ATE or manual testing.  Here's a typical product flow.  Note that I have left out some steps.

1. Install components on the PWB.  This is usually a solder reflow operation, though there may be some manual operation for specific parts.
2. AOI (optical) inspection
3. Rework as required
4. Manual inspection
5. Attach (solder) connector to the board
6. Inspection
7. Half dozen or so temperature cycles
8. Test at ambient, cold, and hot
9. Clean and conformal coat
10. More manual visual inspections
11. One final test at ambient
12. Final inspection

This flow is oriented to finding problems as early in the production process as possible.  You don't want a marginal part or bad solder joint to only be uncovered during final test of the system, or after it's been delivered to the customer.

Comment: This is really interesting! Particularly interesting to me how much manual visual inspections are involved. How fast can someone do a manual inspection? Do they have to be well-trained to do it?

Comment: A good inspector can pick up on things an AOI tool may miss.  AOI tools are improving all the time, but they are used to pick up the "gross" manufacturing defects.  How fast depends on the complexity of the board.  An hour or two would my guess for a 6"x8" board populated to 25 mil SMT parts and a BGA or two.  And yes, they have to be well trained, and go through refresher training on a regular basis.  Needless to say, this does not come cheap.

Comment: Whoa, you're saying that for every board of this type (sounds somewhat but not insanely complex) that's manufactured, a human inspector spends 1-2 hours inspecting it? That sounds super expensive! Or is this only for some boards?

Comment: Every board.  Yes, it's expensive.  But cheaper in the long run than having a problem at a higher level of integration. These are not cheapo consumer products that you throw away every couple of years.

Comment: Thanks! What kind of industries have this process? And how would the process differ for a consumer device?